# boost::asio::async_read receiving EOF before receiving the complete Content-Length

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am implementing an HTTP File download client using Boost ASIO. I am using the async_read operation. The problem I am facing is in the async_read I am receiving the EOF before receiving the full content (i.e Content-Length), this is happening irrespective of the content size. Given is my read operation

```
void Http::ResumableAsyncDownload::read_content(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t _size)
{
    try {
        if ( !err)
        {
            received_bytes += _size;
            if ( ofs_.is_open() ) {
            // Write all of the data that has been read so far.
            ofs_ << &response_;
        } else {
            ofs_.open(std::string(params_.tempdir + "/" + params_.partnumber).c_str());
            if ( ofs_.is_open() ) {
                ofs_ << &response_;
            } else {
                DEBUG_MSG("Error while opening file to store downloaded data. File Path = %s\n", std::string(params_.tempdir + "/" + params_.partnumber).c_str());
                std::cout << ("Unable to open local file for storing downloaded data");
            }
        }
        // Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
        boost::asio::async_read(*ssocket_, response_,
                            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                            boost::bind(&ResumableAsyncDownload::read_content, this, _1, _2)
                        );
        }
        else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            DEBUG_MSG("[NET] : Exception in ResumableAsyncDownload in read_content : %s\n", err.message().c_str());
            std::cout << ("Asynchronous File Download Error: " + err.message());
        }

        if(err == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            std::cout << "[RESPONSE] : EOF: We are not breaking connection\n";
            ssocket_->shutdown();
            delete ssocket_;
            ssocket_ = NULL;
            delete ctx;
            ctx      = NULL;

            if ( (content_length != received_bytes) && !(params_.get_size) ) {
                std::cout << "Failed to receive complete data packet. Content Length = " << content_length << " Received Bytes = " << received_bytes << std::endl;
            // ofs_.clear();
            }
        }
    } catch ( std::exception &ex ) {
        std::cout << "We have an exception. Exception = " << std::string(ex.what()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So for example, the Content-Length is say 292309324, but I will receive EOF before 292309324.

To overcome this problem I have implemented the Chunked download using the HTTP Range header, but in that case for every chunk I request I receive less than the requested chunk, then I re-calculate the next range, it works before the last chunk. I never receive the last chunk and usually the situation is (i.e)

```
Range for last chunk 227376464-227376641/227376641 
Requested Bytes = 178
```

Response Headers

```
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Content-Range: bytes 227376464-227376641/227376641
Server: WildFly/9
Content-Length: 178
Accept-Ranges: bytes
OperationId: 4a847024-2348-42bd-af7d-3638e41cba4f
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 11:41:18 GMT
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=04-84FRD2128G0US; path=/
Cache-control: private
```

As you can see, the server is responding with good range of the last chunk but in the read_content is giving EOF.

So in both approaches read_content is not reading the complete data and giving EOF. As I understand EOF is the socket closed by the server and can also cause short-read but isn't my chunked download solution. Shouldn't I receive the last chunked packet in full.

Any thoughts on whats going wrong ? Please also note that I am calling a custom API to download the file but I am seeing the same issue even if I download from some public link (i.e http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso), so I do not think the issue is at my server side. Also note that I do not see this issue if I use the synchronous version of boost::asio::async_read (i.e boost::asio::read). I am using Boost version 1.55 compiled for ARM.

Comment: When you are getting the eof, you should also check the number of bytes received.  Actually, you should always check the number of bytes received.  the eof is telling you should expect no more bytes, but some bytes may have been buffered.

Comment: When I receive EOF, there is no data in the buffer. The returned size is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a total byte counter to your `Http` class `size_t bytes_transferred_total_;` and ditching `err == boost::asio::error::eof`. You know the total size as that is part of the original HTTP header `Content-Length: <total_body_size>` which you've parsed. The amended code would look something like this:

```
...
if (!err) {
  received_bytes += _size;
  bytes_transferred_total_ += _size;
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
boost::asio::async_read(
    *ssocket_, response_, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
    boost::bind(&ResumableAsyncDownload::read_content, this, _1, _2));
// continue reading until all data has been received
if (bytes_transferred_total_ >= content_length_from_header_) {
  // you've received it all
}
```

In initializing `content_length_from_header_` make sure you understand that it represents the size of the body itself, excluding the header.

Footnote: Instead of `boost::bind` or `std::bind` consider using lambdas as they are generally more performant, e.g. allowing compilers to inline them. Unless, of course, you need to exploit `bind`'s dynamic nature.

Comment: Tried this but when I receive the EOF I get 0 data and if my last data chunk is say 170 bytes (reported in the Content-Length) but data is of 0 size, so I never get into the completion condition you have mentioned above (i.e bytes_transferred_total_ >= content_length_from_header_ ), so my total transferred bytes are always less than content-length.

Comment: a) not sure how liberally you use the term "chunk". For HTTP it has a special meaning. There are a couple of ways how the other side knows when a transfer is over: using `Content-Length`, chunked transfer (where you read until you receive a chunk of size 0), until connection closes.
b) if either side reports incorrect `Content-Length` that's your indication where to look for a problem.
c) make sure you have the right `content_length_from_header_` as I mentioned
d) headers are only sent at the beginning of the transfer, if you receive them mid transfer, something is off

Comment: Also, writing your own HTTP parser is not trivial, if you framework allows, check this out http://cpp-netlib.org/

Comment: I am loosely using the word chunk here, not what it meant in HTTP. I do not think I have problem in my logic (I may be wrong), my problem is if I try to download a 2 MB file, async_read function terminates with EOF without reading all the data (i.e 1.9 MB), however I am receiving the good Content-Length in the response header but the body is empty or body is giving me say 1.4 MB of data. I have tried to use Range feature of HTTP to work around this but in this case for my last data block I never receive the last bytes.

Comment: I am not receiving headers in the mid neither I am including headers in the Content-Length. To me it looks like problem is in the async_read method. My algorithm to distribute the full 2MB in multiple byte ranges works perfect if I use boost::asio::read function. But I need to use boost::asio::async_read function to detect network dis-connectivity.

Comment: Instead of `boost::asio::async_read()` try using `ssocket_->async_read_some()` to get complete control. Otherwise, I am at wits end since I don't see the whole implementation.